# Is @JsonProperty annotation required on accessor methods?

Tags: java, jackson

I've inherited the following:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
public class MyClass {
  @JsonProperty("id")
  private String id;

  @JsonProperty("id")
  public String getId(){
    ...code...
  }

  @JsonProperty("id")
  public String setId(String id) {
    ...code...
  }
}
```

Are the repeated JsonProperty annotations required on the getter and setter, or would jackson handle the serialization/deserialization automatically if I only annotated the private member?

Comment: Are those getters and setters actually private?

Comment: You can have the annotation only on private variables

Comment: @chrylis - they weren't meant to be. Have updated.

Comment: I've inherited those projects as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example, and with default `ObjectMapper` settings, no annotations should be needed, when using Jackson 1.8 or newer.

Jackson can auto-detect properties from public getters (like "public int getValue()"), setters ("public void setValue(int v);" and fields ("public int value;").
In addition, as long as one public setter, getter or field is found, then matching but (otherwise) non-visible setter/field is also included.

Note, however, that with old Jackson versions (1.7 and earlier) did NOT do second part, and both setter and getter needed to be public.

Answer (score 4):

You definitely don't need all those `@jsonProperty`. Jackson mapper can be initialized to sereliazie/deserialize according to getters or private members, you of course need only the one you are using. By default it is by getters.

To define the mapper by members:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
    mapper.disable(MapperFeature.AUTO_DETECT_GETTERS);
```

I would recommend anyway also to add this definition:

```
   mapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_SINGLE_QUOTES, true);
```

Comment: For boolean accessors starting with `is`, also `disable(MapperFeature.AUTO_DETECT_IS_GETTERS)`